# Read values from a .csv file into a list dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .csv file with one column called `Trigger` and two other columns called `void1` and `void2`.

The data looks like this:

```
Trigger;void1;void
good;not good;not to good;
```

I would like to use this data to create a dictionary that looks like this:

```
dictionary ={"good":["not good", "not to good"]}
```

I used the following code to start:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dictionary.csv', sep =";")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    dictionary[row['trigger']] = row['void1']
```

Which works. However when I try:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dictionary.csv', sep =";")

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    dictionary[row['trigger']] = row['void1', 'void2']
```

It doesn't work. Any ideas how I can get the output I am looking for?

Comment: How about `dictionary[row['trigger']] = [row['void1'], row['void2']]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Numpy works like standard Python Lists, you need to change this line:

```
    dictionary[row['trigger']] = row['void1', 'void2']
```

To:

```
    dictionary[row['trigger']] = [row['void1'], row['void2']]
```

Also assuming that your CSV File actually looks like this:

```
    Trigger;void1;void2
    good;not good;not to good;
```

instead of this:

```
    Trigger;void1;void
    good;not good;not to good;
```

Also notice that your first example does not save the entries as you wanted it to. You are storing a String as dictionary value instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Please access only one column from `row` at a time:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    dictionary[row['trigger']] = [row['void1'], row['void2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

In pandas you can have a list inside the index operator (`[]`) in order to select the columns you want. You were almost there with the `row['void1', 'void2']` syntax, you just need a second group of brackets:

```
dictionary[row['trigger']] = row[['void1', 'void2']].tolist()
```

You then call `tolist` because `row[['void1', 'void2']]` will return a Series object instead of a plain list.